# Extrinsic calibration of a multicamera-rig mounted rigidly on a mobile robot

Tags: mobile-robot, cameras, calibration

We have a set of 8 cameras mounted rigidly on a mobile robot. The cameras are forming an arc, which allows a 360º vision.

I want the extrinsic parameters of them referred to the robot. Is there any ROS package that allows that? If not, how can I do that?

I was thinking of doing some stereo calibrations between the pairs of cameras. Then, refer all the cameras to the same camera system with simple transformations.

Edit: Other option is doing something like in https://www.researchgate.net/publication/329600906_Charuco_Board-Based_Omnidirectional_Camera_Calibration_Method

In this paper they propose a Charuco board-based cube structure to calibrate the camera rig. But the problem is that I must make the cube on my own and can introduce some errors.

Any help?
Thank you!!

Comment: Where is the center of the robot? Will he finding the relative pose between the cameras and a marker on the for be enough?

Answer (score 1):

The [ar_track_alvar](http://wiki.ros.org/ar_track_alvar) offers a neat way to locate the pose of each camera relative to multiple marker tags. By aggregating the information from multiple tags you should be able to get a robust measurement.